# how to recode this efficiently?

Tags: python, performance

I have the following class

```py
class Problem:
    def __init__(self, instance: Instance):
        self.instance = instance
        self.solution =  Solution.empty_solution()

    def _compute_start_end(self):
        ....

        return start, end

    def _fuction_1(self):
        start, end = self._compute_start_end()
        ....

    def _function_2(self):
        start, end = self._compute_start_end()
        ....
```

The functions 1 and 2  will be called once and only once for each object of this type.
However, since I computed the `start` and `end` in  `_function_1`, I don't want to recompute it when calling `_function_2`.  How to avoid this?

Comment: Assign the values to a global variable when computed in function 1 and use it in function 2.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The simplest solution is to add `@functools.lru_cache(None)` as a decorator to _compute_start_end.  This says that if I ever call this function again with the exact same arguments, just return whatever value was returned the previous time.  Then just call `function_1` and `function_2` in whatever order you want however many times you want.

Comment: @FrankYellin How does this compare to making `start` and `end` as attributes?

Comment: Alternatively, change `_compute_start_end` to look at an instance variable `_start_end`, which you initialize to None in your `__init__` method.  If it's still `None`, compute the values, and add `self._start_end = start, end` before the return statement.  Otherwise, just return `self._start_end`.

Comment: I tend to use @functools.lru_cache(None).  It's slightly more heavy-weight (it can deal with checking the arguments), but it works right out of the box.  I don't have to think about making sure I've caught every return statement in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Since we need to execute the function just once, but we don't know if `function_1` is executed first `function_2`, you can use the following ideas:

1. If possible, you can call the `compute` function in the `init` method itself.

```py
def __init__(self, params):
    ....
    self._compute_start_end()
def _compute_start_end(self):
    ....
    self.start, self.end = start, end
def function_1(self):
    #use self.start and self.end
def function_2(self):
    #use self.start and self.end instead of recomputing
```

2. If that declaration doesn't work for your program for some reason, you can check whether the function has been called or not using a simple check.

```py
def __init__(self, params):
    ....
    self.start, self.end = None, None
def _compute_start_end(self):
    if (self.start or self.end):
        return
    ....
    self.start, self.end = start, end
def function_1(self):
    self._compute_start_end()
    #use self.start and self.end
def function_2(self):
    self._compute_start_end()
    #use self.start and self.end instead of recomputing
```

As long as you're not assigning `None` to both `start` and `end`, the computation will only happen once.

Comment: But no one is calling `_compute_start_end` now.  The variables will never bet set.

Comment: Still may not work.  They never says that `function_1` is called before `function_2`, just that they're only called once.  (Original poster corrected me when I wrote about function_1 being called first.)

Comment: @FrankYellin made modifications for that as well

Answer (score 2):

Okay.  Other people are doing theirs as answers rather than comments.  I'll put mine here, too.

I prefer

```
@functools.lru_cache(None)
def _compute_start_end(self):
     ....
```

and be done with it.

All the other solutions are correct, but they rely on the programmer remembering to call `_compute_start_end` once before either `_function_1` or `_function_2` has been called.  Telling Python to just cache the result of `_compute_start_end` makes this code more resilient to future changes.

Comment: I don't see why `function 1` has to called before :p

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to recompute 'start, end', then just make them as instance variables

```
self.start = #Some Value
self.end = #Some Value
```

Then when you call function_2 after calling function_1, you can do something like

```
    def _fuction_2(self):
        start, end = self.start, self.end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

## Store values inside class

This is probably the most basic thing you could do: just store `start` and `end` inside the class. Sometimes this is called "lazy initialization".

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self._start, self._end = None, None

    def _compute_start_end(self):
        if not self._start and not self._end:
            self._start, self._end = real_compute()
        return self._start, self._end

    def _function1(self):
        start, end = self._compute_start_end()

    def _function2(self):
        start, end = self._compute_start_end()
```

Alternatively, you could compute `_start` and `_end` in constructor.

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self):
        self._start, self._end = self._compute_start_end()

    def _compute_start_end(self):
        ...
        return computed_start, computed_end

    def _function1(self):
        foo(self._start, self._end)

    def _function2(self):
        bar(self._start, self._end)
```

## memoize

You could also use a technique called "memoization", which in Python is available as [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). This basically remembers results of function call with a set of arguments, caches it and returns it instead of running the function.

This is nice if you don't want to clutter your class with artificial members.

```
from functools import lru_cache

class Problem:
    @lru_cache
    def _compute_start_end(self):
        ...
        return start, end
```

If you use Python 3.9, you can also use [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), which is a smaller and faster version of `lru_cache`.

Comment: why adding `if not self._start and not self._end` ? I mean, well when I call the first function (`function_1` or `function_2`) I call the `compute_start_end` function which will modify  both `self.start` and `self.end`. Then ,  wen calling the second function, I simply  use `self.start` and `self.end` without the need to pass by `compute_start_end` another time. Am I right?
`

Comment: Because if you ever want to change a call order or add another function, you don't have to remember the correct order of function calls and could always use values returned by `_compute_start_end()` instead of accessing them directly. Or you could just compute them in constructor.

Comment: But what if you call the second function first.  Then you haven't calculated the values yet.  You said previously that either function_1 or function_2 can be called first.  You need to call compute_start_end, and let **it** decide whether it's been called already or not.

Comment: and what is the difference with   `self._start, self._end = self._compute_start_end()
` ?